# How to share PPPoE connection via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wifi, connection, internet, wifi-direct

I build wifi router for my house in the countryside. I only can have internet via wireless so I buy USB grid antenna and connect on PI and made a bridge to internal antenna. USB antenna is connected to internet provider via PPPoE connection what I setup via `pppoeconfig` and internal antenna share this network in my house.

The problem is that I can access to Raspberry PI via my laptop but internet not pass via that bridge.

Also I setup static IP because sql and apache server what I need.

How to broadcast internet via this network?

Here is my configuration from /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
#gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static

address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.1.1
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat


  # wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static

address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
#gateway 192.168.1.1

   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
allow-hotplug wlan1
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static

address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
#gateway 192.168.1.1

   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set wlan1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto -wlan1
iface -wlan1 inet manual
```

Comment: Make sure `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: Where to add that?

Comment: Run the command as `root` user in terminal.

Comment: Did you enable `MASQUERADE` in `/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` ?

Comment: Interesting is that iptables.ipv4.nat is empty. What need to be there?